# MySql Database - Visual Export

Tags: mysql

I have a Local MySql Database for a site I built a while ago - around 60 tables/views.
I'm doing version 2 of the site and wanted to get a visual export of the database if possible so I can see what I've done and what needs to be changed etc for the updated site.

Is there a way to get a visual/graphical view of the database tables/views etc?

eg: see each table and the columns names it holds and preferable the type of data - int(10) etc.

thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Try [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) - it can import your schema and give you a graphical view.